# K. Janich, Vector Analysis, Chapter 3 Test

Tags: manifolds, vector-analysis, differential-forms

In the text by Klaus Janich, "Vector Analysis," there is a Test at the end of Chapter 3, on Differential Forms.  Question #6 reads:

> Let $M$ be a nonempty manifold with $\dim M = n, n > 0$ and $0 < k < n$. Then, $\dim \Omega^{k}M = {}$
>
> 1. $\infty$,
> 2. $\displaystyle\binom{n}{k}$,
> 3. $k(k-1)/2$.

The answer key in the back of the book says #1 is the correct answer.  This makes no sense to me.  I believe the correct answer should be #2, $\binom{n}{k}$.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the definition of $\Omega^k M$, which is presumably the space of $k$-forms on $M$.

Comment: Well if $\Omega^k$ is the space of $k$-covariant tensor fields on $M$, it is infinite-dimensional as a vector space over $\mathbb R$, just like $C^\infty(\mathbb R)$ is infinite-dimensional over $\mathbb R$

Comment: You're thinking of $\bigwedge^k T^\ast_p M$, the space of $k$-forms on the single tangent space at a fixed point $p$. However, $\Omega^k(M)$ can be thought of as a space of functions assigning one such form to every point on $M$. And that space should intuitively have way higher dimension.

Answer (score 3):

Recall that $C^\infty(M)$ is a vector space over $\mathbb{R}$, in the usual way by pointwise operations. Given $f, g: M \to \mathbb{R}$ and $r \in \mathbb{R}$, the sum $f+g$ and the scalar multiple $rf$ are defined by
\begin{align}
(f+g)(m) &= f(m) + g(m), \\
(rf)(m) &= r \, f(m)
\end{align}
for all $m \in M$. This is an (uncountably) infinite dimensional as a vector space over $\mathbb{R}$.

Now, on a coordinate patch $U \subseteq M$, for $0 \leq k \leq n$, the space of $k$-forms $\Omega^k(U)$ is a (free) module over the ring $C^\infty(U)$ with a basis
$$
\bigl\{ dx^I = dx^{i_1} \wedge \cdots \wedge dx^{i_k} \bigr\}, 
$$
where the multi-index sets $I = (i_1, \dots, i_k)$ run over all $k$-subsets, which for our convenience, we can sort to satisfy
$$
1 \leq i_1 \leq \cdots \leq i_k \leq n.
$$
This basis set clearly has dimension $\displaystyle\binom{n}{k}$ **as a module over $C^\infty(U)$.**

Using bump functions and a partition of unity, at least in the case that $M$ is paracompact, these arguments extend to show that the space of forms over the whole manifold $M$ is finite-dimensional. Examples include: compact spaces, normal spaces, metric spaces, smooth CW complexes.

However **as a vector space over $\mathbb{R}$, the space $\Omega^k(M)$ is infinite-dimensional.** Even for $k=0$, where $\Omega^0(M) \cong C^\infty(M)$ it's infinite-dimensional.

Comment: The basis elements $dx^I$ are only defined on a single coordinate patch, and will only be globally defined for manifolds that can be covered with a single patch.

Comment: Sure, that's true, but via bump functions and partitions of unity, a form on a patch extends to the entire manifold, hence doesn't affect the finiteness argument.

Comment: This argument requires that our manifold can be covered by finitely many coordinate patches, since partitions of unity are only guaranteed to be locally finite.

Comment: @J.V.Gaiter, I edited my answer to carve out the case of non-paracompact spaces that don't admit any partition of unity subordinate to a locally finite cover.

Comment: @ Sammy Black. Ah, got it!  Trick question. 
Thanks for the clarification.